# How to show a dialog with transparent barrier?

Tags: dart, flutter

Currently i have a simple dialog, but it have a barrier of somewhat translucent black color, i  want to make it fully transparent, any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, there is no straightforward property to do so. but if you really want to achieve this to change the color of the background overlay, you can edit the `barrierColor` property directly in the Dialog class by flutter.

This property doesnt really accept transparent color, so you can just set it to Black color with opacity of 0.01 that will do the same work.

Comment: Never edit Flutter code because you will lose everything after new version is released.

Answer (score 2):

for the fully transparent to dialog you can set these attribute of `simple dialog`

try this:

```
elevation: 0.0,
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
```

this is working for me, check it

```
showDialog(context: context, child:
      new SimpleDialog(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: new Text("Simple Dialog"),
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:24.0),
            child: Text("Simple dialog example"),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context), child: Text("CANCEL")),
              FlatButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context), child: Text("ACCEPT")),
            ],
          ),
        ],

      )
    );
```

Comment: not working. this just remove the shadow around the borders of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieve the dialog with transparent background

STEP 1: Set the opacity to the barier to make the background translucent.

```
showDialog(
      barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return showLoadingDialog(context);
      },
);
```

**Step 2: In your dialog widget, set background to transparent and remove elevation**

```
Widget showLoadingDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      elevation: 0.0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: const [
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
          SizedBox(height: 50),
          Text(
            "Authenticating...",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 18,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

barrier color can be changed with property `barrierColor: Colors.transparent` in show dialog

```
return showDialog<void>(
 context: context,
 barrierColor: Colors.transparent, // default would be black54 
 // change to transparent or any other color as you wish
 builder: (BuildContext context) {
   return Dialog(child: Container());
  );
 });
```